# Control space before and after specific cmidrule in tabular

Tags: spacing, booktabs

I would like the space after the `\cmidrule`s to be reduced. However, `belowrulesep` affects all the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llrrrrrr}
  \toprule
  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{fov=\ang{50}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{fov=\ang{200}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{fov=\ang{350}} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \\
  &  & VB1 & VB$\infty$ & VB1 & VB$\infty$ & VB1 & VB$\infty$ \\
  Search time (s) & {\sc HallwayEasy} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  & {\sc HallwayHard} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  & {\sc TwoHallway} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  \midrule
  Path length (m) & {\sc HallwayEasy} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  & {\sc HallwayHard} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  & {\sc TwoHallway} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  \midrule
  Closed nodes & {\sc HallwayEasy} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  & {\sc HallwayHard} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  & {\sc TwoHallway} & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
  \midrule
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]

Comment: Leave out the `\\ ` which is just after the `cmidrule`s

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comment (only a `\\ ` in excess).

Comment: unrelated but you should probably use `\textsc{zzz}` rather than `{\sc zzzz}` as `\sc` isn't defined by default in latex.

Comment: Thought I do not need it, I would still be interested in an answer to controlling the space above and below a rule. Is `\vspace` or `\vskip` appropriate?